# Are there any web services or other APIs that let you purchase something without having to set up an account first?

Tags: web-services

I am trying to prototype a system that will display a list of choices to a user, and allow them to place an order for the one they select (an over simplification of the prototype, but sufficient to get to the point). I have the users credit card number, billing and shipping addresses, and other contact information, but I can't find any web services that will let me actually purchase something with this information to complete the prototype. I have checked directories such as [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory) and [Xmethods](http://www.xmethods.net/ve2/Directory.po), but they just seem to point to APIs that let you check for prices and availability, but not actually place an order. Does such a thing exist, or is there some reason (such as security) that I am missing, that prevents such a service from being offered?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing about online shopping is the security of transmitted information (e.g. credit card data). So the ideal case is to transmit these information directly to the related bank's (issuer of the credit card) payment services, rather than passing it via other service providers. This is what 3-D Secure does.

So when you use a common API this means putting an extra broker between, and passing the secure information to this party which increases vulnerability. Since such a broker cannot use 3-D secure (since it is not the merchant so not possible to make an agreement with the banks) and it should pass the information to online shopping site.

Moreover, an online shoping site can block traffic coming from such an intermediary webservice at any time if you do not make an obligatory agreement and making agreements for each online merchant is practically not very possible.

Comment: I can write a webbot using something like Python Mechanize to do what I want, so why don't vendors provide something a little more convenient and secure, like a web services API?

Comment: what do you mean by "vendors"? do you mean online shops like amazon.com?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such free API available the simple reason behind that information like credit card  is very secure and confidential and there will security threat on free API's.

here is list of best 10 online payment system

http://sixrevisions.com/tools/online-payment-systems/

and this one who providing live demo

http://www.fastcharge.com/

Comment: These online payment systems would need to be implemented by a vendor. Do you know any who have?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible though I don't know in depth information. I think this is what you see. In next steps you will be redirected to payment gateway of the bank and then you can complete the transactions just by answering some security questions. I think this is a service you should obtain from the bank. And I haven't seen any universal API that can perform the task you have mentioned.

[Dialog GSM - Sri Lanka](http://mydialog.dialog.lk/bill/)

[Anything.lk - Sri Lanka](http://www.anything.lk/)

Comment: I can't obtain a service from the bank, the vendor would have to. Do you know of any vendor who has?